# Netrw in Neovim is hiding all files created inside a parameterised route in Sveltekit, how can I display them?

Tags: neovim, netrw

While working with Sveltekit in Neovim I ran into an issue with Netrw.

When I create a parameterised route (e.g. "[cardId]"), all files that I create inside it are hidden.

How can I make these files show up? For now, I'm just searching for the files in Treesitter but it's a pain because a lot of the files are required to be the same name by Sveltekit.

I've searched for other people working with Sveltekit and Neovim and no one else seems to have reported this issue so I'm at a total loss.